# How to profile Performance (RAM, CPU usage) from MonoDevelop of Unity3D application?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

So It is pretty eazy how to debug from MD (attach to Unity and here you go - line by line), but I wonder If it is possible to get any visual profiling of my game app in MD. How to profile Performance (RAM, CPU usage) from MonoDevelop that looks on Unity3D that debugs an application?

Answer (score 0):

You need the pro version. See [Unity - Profiler](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Profiler.html) to get an impression.